# Selenium - Stored Session Data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have search throughout the internet but none of the answers I found have a clear solution.

I am using selenium webdriver with Java.

My test needs to verify when you save your login information and close the browser and reopen it then those credentials remain and are saved on a new session. So I want to close the current session and reopen it in order to verify if a cookie persists on the page however Selenium deletes all stored session data so the test case will always fail. Is there any way to prevent Selenium from deleting the stored session data after closing the browser for the specific test case?

When I do run it I get a no such session error.

Comment: Do you use Selenium-Server with Selenium-WebDriver as described here? http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server  In that case run Selenium-Server with option:  -browserSessionReuse: stops re-initialization and spawning of the
    browser between tests

Comment: @Würgspaß unfortunately I do not.

Comment: How do you close the session in your test code? Could you give us a code snippet?

Comment: @Würgspaß I use driver.close().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution works for chrome .

When you launch chrome (I think same applies for other browsers ) selenium creates a temporary profile and when you close it it deletes it. So when you relaunch the browser the new profile will not have the session information. What you can do is use profiles.

```
 DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

 options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\"+System.getenv("USERNAME")+"\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1");
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 driver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

This way  if you create your driver, every time chrome will be launched with the same profile and **if you dont do**

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Your session information will persist in the new session of chrome driver. If you dont want it to persist you can clean the cookies using the above command or just simple log out. This should solve your problem. Similar things should also be possible in other browsers.

To know which profile is currently used type `chrome://version/` in your address bar it has the information of the current profile being usesd. To know more about see [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Comment: @Robben Did this help ?

Comment: great . You are Welcome !

Comment: You have to pass the options by parameter `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`