# In parallel execution, safari browser navigate to url with out login page automatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am using selenium web driver 2.48 and safari driver 2.48 and safari version 8.0.8

I am facing a problem on running my test execution in safari driver.The problem is

```
"In parallel execution, if in one safari window,login is successfull, than in other 
safari windows, this login page is not shown, 

that means safri navigate to url with 
out login as one safari window already complete login."
```

and for this reason, i am facing below issue in parallel execution:

```
"CSRF verification failed.Request aborted"
```

I want like that for parallel execution:

```
if five safari browser window open, in each window, login page will be appeared.

In a sense, each safari driver instance will not share other safari driver  
instances resources or any other thing
```

I have changed safari preferences settings but its not helping.

Is there any   best way to declare safari driver or i need to add any desired capabilities or 
    any other things in safari preferences or any any good suggestion.

please and thanks.

i am using the following code:

```
SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
dc.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);

currentDriver = new SafariDriver(dc);


Set<Cookie> cookies = currentDriver.manage().getCookies();
currentDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
if(!cookies.isEmpty())
    {

    Iterator<Cookie> iter=  currentDriver.manage().getCookies().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
                Cookie C = iter.next();                     
          }
     cookies.clear();

    }
```

Comment: How are you now creating your driver instances. It should not happen as by default each browser instance should have a new temp profile.

Comment: like below:



if (browser.equals("safari")) {
   currentDriver = new SafariDriver();
  }


I have made sure null checking.

Comment: actually it will be helpful for me if i know  how safari driver instance will not share other safari driver  
instances resources and how session is cleared in parallel execution.

My code works fine in chrome and mozilla firefox parallel execution, problem occures only in safari driver.

code for Driver instance creation is like this, i dont use any other things except null checking.

Comment: are you using Windows ? i hope you gone through it https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5 and safari version 8.0.8

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not used safari before. And as you said that the behavior in all other browsers are as you expect it to be. I would like you to try the following.
There is a way by which you can specify the profile of the driver instance to be used. I would suggest you to create separate profiles for each instance and try out . How to do that is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33637374/888070). This answer explains how to use same profile each time . You need to use a different profile each time. ( Which happens by default in chrome not sure why it wouldn't for safari )

Comment: thanks for ur response. There's no such thing as a "profile" with Safari. If anyone wants a clean session, he need to set cleanSession in the safari.options dictionary of  desired capabilities what i already did in my code........... :(

Comment: yeah i read.. i guess you are correct .. you need to switch account in safari , they dont have profile concept