# Python selenium how to load the browser's data(cookies or bookmarks)

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

When using selenium to open a web page, it automatically deletes all cookies u had saved in browser which is inconvenient.

Find solution in this page [java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636679/selenium-stored-session-data)
but don't know how to solve the problem using Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point the browser to a profile file (that's what the java example in the given link is doing)

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=<path to chrome profile>') 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

On Linux the `<path to chrome profile>` is `/home/<user>/.config/google-chrome`.

Comment: for ubuntu i have chrome profile path in `/home/<user>/.config/chromium/Default`. You can check chrome profile path by using `chrome://version` in your chrome browser